# hosting git repository, can't clone: ssh error: bad file number

Tags: windows, apache, git, ssh, clone

I followed this tutorial :http://www.jeremyskinner.co.uk/2010/07/31/hosting-a-git-server-under-apache-on-windows/
to host a git repository on a windows server

steps:
install git & create a test repository
install Apache (I'm using wamp server and it was installed before git)
edit httpd.conf, add:

```
<Directory />
    Allow from all
</Directory>
SetEnv GIT_PROJECT_ROOT C:/wamp/www/repositories
SetEnv GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL
ScriptAliasMatch \
        "(?x)^/(.*/(HEAD | \
                        info/refs | \
                        objects/(info/[^/]+ | \
                                 [0-9a-f]{2}/[0-9a-f]{38} | \
                                 pack/pack-[0-9a-f]{40}\.(pack|idx)) | \
                        git-(upload|receive)-pack))$" \
                        "C:/Program Files/Git/libexec/git-core/git-http-backend.exe/$1"
```

i know this is rather unsafe, but i'm just triing to get the basics working first
so i restart apache
and then i try to clone the repository from a desktop computer with the command:

```
git clone xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx/repositories/Test.git
```

and the output is:

```
Cloning into Test...
ssh: connect to host smarttelecom.no-ip.org port 22: Bad file number
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

what did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the HTTP portocol. By default git uses ssh which you don't want. Try to prefix the url with `http://`

Comment: ok, now i get: Cloning into Test...
fatal: http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx/repositories/Test.git/info/refs not found: did you run git update-server-info on the server?

Comment: @Berty: Sorry, I never used cloning over HTTP. But as the output suggest, you may have to run `git update-server-info`?